# Obtener fecha desde bd sql server por medio del reader["columna"] con formato dd/mm/yyyy y hora hh:mm:ss en en C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, server

¿Como obtener fecha desde bd sql server por medio del reader["columna"] con formato dd/mm/yyyy y hora hh:mm:ss en en C#?

Las fechas que estoy obteniendo, provienen de columanas del tipo 'datetime'

Aquí está la forma de validar un Reader Null para el caso de las fechas de modificación vacias y la forma de dar formato a la fecha. Obs: los / deben incluir el '/', por que de otra forma vendría dd-mm-yyyy con guión
[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Considera [edit] tu pregunta y agregar tu codigo en texto y no una imagen.

Comment: Toda la razón Kenny! En realidad queria contribuir, no preguntan, pero Stack no me lo permite por que soy nuevo en esta cuenta.

Comment: La red StackExchange tiene la opcion de contestar tu propia pregunta, si a eso te refieres. Incluso en este momento, puedes contestar tu propia pregunta, y asi contribuir a la informacion disponible del sitio.